# 8 Souls of a Great Champion while invading. Did I just get lucky?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I invaded some world and got destroyed by the host + 2 friends they summoned.

However, while the host was summoning friends, I picked up what looked like a small bag made out of fabric from the ground near him (I was trying not do die and I was nervous, so don't trust my memory too much on what the object looked like).

It turned out to be 8 Souls of a Great Champion!

Why would they just be there on the ground? Should I be invading people all the time and looking for loot like that? Did I maybe just happen to barge in when they were in the middle of trading souls with another player?

Comment: The game has been out for a while, and item duplication in dark souls III is so easy  that it is quite simple to get a full inventory of 699 souls, embers, etc. Many players give these ill-gotten items as gifts to lower level players, as they have no more need of them after a certain point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

People will sometimes drop items, and they will appear as a small bag. This can be for many reasons. Maybe they're giving the items to someone else, maybe they're leaving a trap (something to entice you to a certain spot, to spring an ambush), or maybe they just don't have the space in their inventory.

This isn't a common occurrence. The players usually need to decide to leave the item on the ground. As to why or how this happened though, it's anybody's guess.

Comment: Another common reason for such item stacks is the "swap item" cheat method to spawn items, which works by dropping an item and editing it to what you want. Be careful about picking up items in multiplayer! It could be an invalid item that'll get you banned.